# xticklabels font size in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Here is the current situation.

The problem is that, the font size of the denominator and the numerator of the xticklabels are not same.

I intend to make them in equally size.

How can i achieve that.
The code is attached below.
[image: the current situation]

```
x=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
labels = [r'$\stackrel{1}{5.6}$',r'$\stackrel{2}{11.3}$',r'$\stackrel{3}{16.9}$',
r'$\stackrel{4}{22.6}$',r'$\stackrel{5}{28.2}$',r'$\stackrel{6}{33.9}$']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.canvas.draw()
ax.xaxis.set_ticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels,verticalalignment="top")
ax.tick_params(direction='out', pad=5)
plt.xlabel(r'$\stackrel{f/GHz}{ka}$',fontsize=22)
```

Comment: I can not reproduce this.  Try clearing out all of the cache `~/.cache/matplotlib/tex.cache` ?

Comment: it works in my computer. Does the cache file have influence ?